# Why cleveref references don´t works in this example?

Tags: cleveref

I was compiling with PDFLATEX and appears ?? instead references.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo


\begin{document}

Next you can see the \cref{fig:capitala}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\caption{Thi is capital a}\label{fig:capitala}
\end{figure}
%\vspace{1cm}

And the \cref{tab:one}, in the \cpageref{tab:twentyfour}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{subtable}{.19\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$x_i$ & $f(x_i)$ \\
\hline
 1 & 1.2\\
  2 & 0.4\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.19\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$x_i$ & $f(x_i)$ \\
\hline
23 & 6.8\\
24 & 4.0\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
%
%
\caption{24 values}\label{tab:twentyfour}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cleveref` must be loaded _after_ `hyperref`; c.f. [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1868/21344).

Comment: Downvoted because `texdoc cleveref` clearly states that "Basically, cleveref must be loaded last."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed by Paul Gessler, cleveref is one of the packages that has to be loaded `after   hyperref`. Also, you had a reference not defined by a label (the subtables), so I added one, or rather 2 since you have two subtables, and a `\centering` command (the table caption will be centred anyway, so it would look odd if the table were not).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref} %para crear referencias

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Fuente MathPazo


\begin{document}

Next you can see \cref{fig:capitala}.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\caption{This is capital a}\label{fig:capitala}
\end{figure}
%\vspace{1cm}

And \cref{tab:one}, \cpageref{tab:twentyfour}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subtable}{.19\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$x_i$ & $f(x_i)$ \\
\hline
 1 & 1.2\\
  2 & 0.4\\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{}\label{tab:one}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.19\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$x_i$ & $f(x_i)$ \\
\hline
23 & 6.8\\
24 & 4.0\\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{}\label{tab:two}
\end{subtable}%
%
%
\caption{24 values}\label{tab:twentyfour}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]